# Disabling part of js embedded on page

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm loading a page with content generated by js on load. At the same time part of js embedded on page (not external file) in a simple `<script>` section checks if I have AdBlock and redirects to a page demanding to whitelist the site. Doing that is no trouble, but I got really curious as to how such a setup could be bypassed. So far I managed to save the page to the drive, remove the AdBlock checker script, open it, and it works. But that looks a bit cumbersome, any good way to disable a part of the page's js on load? I tried disabling all js, editing the page live with Chrome Inspect tool, but I have no idea if you can manually rerun the js on page after that without reloading.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done.

When a script is executed, function definitions are added to the global window object. There may be debugging symbols attached to the function that indicate where the function came from, but this information is not available to scripts.

**One possible solution :**

**You can create a small browser plugin to search for the script and remove it even before the page has rendered.**

Comment: Loading scripts is asynchronous, so no, that wouldn't stop it to load.